# Alfresco usage and directions

Tags: java, jsp, alfresco

My purpose is to use Alfresco from my custom java web application. Which direction should I go ? Kindly share your experience with Alfresco similar to my situation.

Edit

I am thinking of customizing Alfresco Share. Alternatively, is there any simple sample application that use Alfresco out there ? I would like to use that as a based structure.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to drive Alfresco from another application, I would rather encourage you to leverage [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) instead of JCR. While the latter would still be an option [using an RMI bridge](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JCR-RMI_Extension), the result would be quite a strongly coupled system, with e.g. poor scalability capabilities.

CMIS is in facts meant to support your use case, while JCR was never meant to be a distributed  protocol. You can read the spec, and have a quick start with the [Apache Chemistry client API](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html).

Alfresco also provides an [online instance](http://cmis.alfresco.com) you can use to run your CMIS tests against a live Alfresco repository.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on a number of things.

1. What does your custom java web application do? Is it similar to Share? Or will it require a lot of customisation? If you do customise the Share, how easy will it be to upgrade to future versions of Share?
2. What are your team's skill sets? Have they done Share development before? Do they have the skills to do it?
3. Can you reuse an existing custom web app you already have?
4. Have you considered using something like Drupal or Liferay as the front end for Alfresco? There are a number of different integrations between Alfresco and these systems out there.
5. Have you seen any of the other custom applications out there? E.g. Flex based solution for Alfresco: http://integratedsemantics.org/.
6. The most simplest way to build applications on top of Alfresco is to use the Web Scripts to return complete HTML pages. E.g. This website is entirely built up using Alfresco Web Scripts. http://whatson.camden.gov.uk/whatson/index.

NB: What ever you decide, if you need to integrate with Alfresco from a remote Application, use CMIS.